# ng-click function logs if and else statement

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my test.js controller the if/else statement log out an object for an ng-click

```
   angular.module('stationeryApp')
  .factory('Cards', function () {
    var Cards = [];
    return Cards
  })
  .controller('TestCtrl', function ($scope, $log, Cards) {
    $scope.cards = Cards
    $scope.cardClick = function () {
      if ($scope.card['fName']!=="" && $scope.card['lName']!=="") {
        $scope.cards.push($scope.card)
        $scope.card={fName:'',lName:''}
        console.log($scope.card);
      } else {
        console.log($scope.card);
      }
    }
  });
```

This is test.HTML:

```
<div>
  <md-toolbar layout='column' layout-align='center'>
        <md-button layout-margin layout-padding flex='100' class='md-raised md-primary'>
          <h1>{{ card.fName }}</h1>
          <h1>{{ card.lName }}</h1>
        </md-button>
        <div layout='column' layout-align='center center' >
          <input type="text" style="color:black;" flex='' ng-model="card.fName">
          <input type="text" style="color:black;" flex='' ng-model="card.lName">
        </div>
  </md-toolbar>
</div>
```

Without the if statement the Cards array has two objects pushed into it for every time cardClick() is invoked. The first object is whatever the ng-model for the inputs are and the second object is **always** the empty strings.

Example:

```
fName input = "Stack"
lName input = "Overflow"
cardClick()
result --> Cards = [{fName:"Stack", lName:"Overflow"},{fName:"",lName:""}]

fName input = "Java"
lName input = "Script"
cardClick()
result --> Cards = [{fName:"Stack", lName:"Overflow"},{fName:"",lName:""},{fName:"Java",lName:"Script"},{fName:"",lName:""}]
```

Including the if statement will yield the desired result

Example:

```
fName input = "Stack"
lName input = "Overflow"
cardClick()
result --> Cards = [{fName:"Stack", lName:"Overflow"}]

fName input = "Java"
lName input = "Script"
cardClick()
result --> Cards = [{fName:"Stack", lName:"Overflow"},{fName:"Java",lName:"Script"}]
```

My question is why does the if statement bring about that result and why does the the if/else statement in test.js log out the if and else result for each time cardClick() is invoked.

EDIT

Here is the code without the if/else. This renders the result in the first example.

```
angular.module('stationeryApp')
  .factory('Cards', function () {
    var Cards = [];
    return Cards
  })
  .controller('TestCtrl', function ($scope, $log, Cards) {
    $scope.cards = Cards
    $scope.cardClick = function () {
        $scope.cards.push($scope.card)
        $scope.card={fName:'',lName:''}
        console.log($scope.card);
    }
  });
```

Comment: You haven't actually provided all the relevant code - which directive uses your TestCtrl? What else does that directive do?

Comment: The controllers and templates were set up using yeoman's angular route generator so I don't believe the issue lies there.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
console.log($scope.card);
```

appears in both your `if` statement and your `else` statement. So you will see that logged either way.

As for the `if/else` question, can you provide your code with `if/else` removed so we can compare?

Comment: Shouldn't the console.log only log for either the if or the else for each click? My problem is that each click logs out both the if and the else for each click.

Comment: So you're seeing `$scope.card` logged twice for each click? If so, I agree that's really odd.